# laravel post -> controller

Tags: php, laravel

I can not understand why this code below is not working:

```
public function subscribe(Request $request){

    $errorsss = [];

    foreach ($request->input() as $key => $input){

        if ($key === 'name') {
            if (empty($request[$key]))
                $errorsss['name'] = 'Msg 1';

        }elseif($key === 'address'){

            if (empty($request[$key]))
                $errorsss['address'] = 'Msg 2';

        }elseif($key === 'email'){

            if (!filter_var($request[$key], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                $errorsss['email'] = 'Msg 3';

        }

        if ($errorsss == null)
            $errorsss = 'none';

    }

    return view('welcome', ['errorsss' => $errorsss, 'request' => $request->input()]);
```

It is just simple form submit, where is checking POST inputs.

I get: **"Illegal string offset 'email'"**

Which refers to  $errorsss['email'] = 'Msg 3'; line.

Can u help me how to fix it please?

Comment: can you provide print_r of your post array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the line

```
if ($errorsss == null)
    $errorsss = 'none';
```

`$errorsss == null` will return true if `$errorsss` is an empty array.

So what happens is, in one iteration of your `foreach` loop, it will come to this line and replace `$errorsss` with a string. So next iteration you try to assign `$errorsss['email']` some value. But `$erorrsss` is a string at this point (no longer an array as you expect it to be), so you get this error.

At a quick glance, your easiest solution is just to remove that line.

Or move it outside of the `foreach` statement, like this:

```
public function subscribe(Request $request) {
    $errorsss = [];

    foreach ($request->input() as $key => $input){
        if ($key === 'name') {
            if (empty($input))
                $errorsss['name'] = 'Msg 1';
        } elseif($key === 'address') {
            if (empty($input))
                $errorsss['address'] = 'Msg 2';
        } elseif($key === 'email') {
            if (!filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                $errorsss['email'] = 'Msg 3';
        }
    }

    if ($errorsss == null)
        $errorsss = 'none';

    return view('welcome', ['errorsss' => $errorsss, 'request' => $request->input()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot used  object type `$request` as array, like this `$request[$key]`

you should simply used `$input` instead

```
public function subscribe(Request $request){

    $errorsss = [];

    foreach ($request->input() as $key => $input){

        if ($key === 'name') {
            if (empty($input))
                $errorsss['name'] = 'Msg 1';

        }elseif($key === 'address'){

            if (empty($input))
                $errorsss['address'] = 'Msg 2';

        }elseif($key === 'email'){

            if (!filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                $errorsss['email'] = 'Msg 3';

        }

        if ($errorsss == null)
            $errorsss = 'none';

    }

    return view('welcome', ['errorsss' => $errorsss, 'request' => $request->input()]);
```